# Error al obtener el mes en Español con strtotime PHP

Tags: php, date

Mi inconveniente es el siguiente. Estoy transformando meses a español por ejemplo:

04 = Abril, 05 = Mayo y así.

El dato fecha lo traigo de una tabla, en un campo tipo date que me trae esto `2018-04-22.`

Ese dato lo divido en 3 con `explode`, porque tengo que mostrar día, mes y año, de forma separada en un certificado.

Pero el valor del mes tengo que mostrarlo en letras y no en numero, y para ello he hecho esta función:

```
function FechaCastellano($date){
 $mes_ = date('F', strtotime($date));
 $_ES = array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
 $_EN = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
 $nombreMes = str_replace($_EN, $_ES, $mes_);
 return $nombreMes;
}
```

El problema es que me esta imprimiendo `ENERO`, y el mes de la fecha es `04`, osea Abril. He hecho echo de la variable `$mes` que le paso a la función aquí:

```
$mes_ES = FechaCastellano($mes);
```

y en efecto contiene un 04, y aun así me esta imprimiendo Enero, y no sé por qué en realidad.

La variable $mes la obtengo de esto:

```
$fecha_examen = explode("-",$funcion[$key]['fecha_examen']);
$dia = $fecha_examen[2];
$mes = $fecha_examen[1];
$year = $fecha_examen[0];
```

Aquí es donde separo la fecha en 3 para poder imprimir cada dato aparte. Pero el problema es que no me imprime en letras el mes que le estoy pasando en números.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@DevJoel te ha indicado el motivo de por qué el código no funciona de la forma esperada.

Leyendo el problema expuesto, yo crearía una `clase` utilitaria (para mi propia biblioteca), y manejaría dentro de ella un objeto `DateTime`. Su flexibilidad daría un alcance único a esta clase, la cual te podría servir para otras cosas futuras, como por ejemplo, traducir los nombres de los días, una representación completa de la fecha, a tu gusto, etc.

La clase podría incorporar también, valiéndose de las facilidades que ofrece `DateTime`, de validaciones previas de la cadena que recibirá como parámetro en el constructor. En resumen, un objeto en sí que podrás utilizar de forma segura en cualquiera de tus aplicaciones.

Este sería un ejemplo simplificado de la clase:

<kbd>**[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/edit/WTGFM42168)**</kbd>

```
/* PHP: Fechas en castellano, clase utilitaria -  https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/158278/29967*/
class FechaEs {
    private $objFecha;
    private $M_es = array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
    private $M_en = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    private $D_es = array("Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernas", "Sábado", "Domingo");
    private $D_en = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");


    public function __construct($mFecha)
    {
            $this->objFecha=DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $mFecha);
    }

    public function getDDDD()
    {
        $nombreDia=$this->objFecha->format('l');
        return str_replace($this->D_en,$this->D_es,$nombreDia);    
    }       

    public function getMM()
    {
        return $this->objFecha->format('m');    
    }

    public function getMMMM(){
        $nombreMes=$this->objFecha->format('F');
        return str_replace($this->M_en,$this->M_es,$nombreMes);    
    }

    public function getYYYY()
    {
        return $this->objFecha->format('Y');    
    }

    public function getYY()
    {
        return $this->objFecha->format('y');    
    }

}
```

### Código de prueba:

```
/*Probando la clase*/

$testFecha=new FechaEs("2018-04-22");
echo "Día (DDDD): ".$testFecha->getDDDD().PHP_EOL;
echo "Mes (MM)  : ".$testFecha->getMM().PHP_EOL;
echo "Mes (MMMM): ".$testFecha->getMMMM().PHP_EOL;
echo "Año (YYYY): ".$testFecha->getYYYY().PHP_EOL;
echo "Año (YY)  : ".$testFecha->getYY().PHP_EOL;

echo PHP_EOL;

$testFecha=new FechaEs("2018-08-22");
echo "Día (DDDD): ".$testFecha->getDDDD().PHP_EOL;
echo "Mes (MM)  : ".$testFecha->getMM().PHP_EOL;
echo "Mes (MMMM): ".$testFecha->getMMMM().PHP_EOL;
echo "Año (YYYY): ".$testFecha->getYYYY().PHP_EOL;
echo "Año (YY)  : ".$testFecha->getYY().PHP_EOL;
```

### Resultado:

```
Día (DDDD): Domingo
Mes (MM)  : 04
Mes (MMMM): Abril
Año (YYYY): 2018
Año (YY)  : 18

Día (DDDD): Miércoles
Mes (MM)  : 08
Mes (MMMM): Agosto
Año (YYYY): 2018
Año (YY)  : 18
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta A. Cedano. Muchísimas Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

El problema es bastante sencillo , la función [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) espera como parámetro una fecha en formato cadena, es aquí donde está su error ya que no está pasando esto si no solo el valor del mes `"04"` .

Entonces hasta este punto hay un paso adicional innecesario ya que si le pasa directamente la fecha sin hacer el `explode` funcionará *(sin modificar su función)*

```
$fecha = $funcion[$key]['fecha_examen'];
$mes_ES = FechaCastellano($fecha );
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/MonumentalWindyPrograms)</kbd>

Si desea  seguir haciéndolo con `explode`,no sería necesario sus dos `arrays` solo bastará con uno ya que le estaría pasando directamente el indice del mes a obtener.

```
function FechaCastellano($mes){
    $_ES = array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");
    return $_ES[$mes-1]; // por tratarse de arrays :)
}

$fecha_examen =  explode("-",$funcion[$key]['fecha_examen']);
$dia = $fecha_examen[2];
//cast para evitar el cero a la izquierda
$mes = (int)$fecha_examen[1];
$year = $fecha_examen[0];
echo FechaCastellano($mes);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/TubbyDizzyInternalcommand)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias Joel, me ha servido tu respuesta!

Answer (score 2):

Ademas de lo expuesto agrego la forma de configurar el locale en un servidor linux Ubuntu

para ver los locale

```
$ locale -a
```

para generar un locale (requiere root)

```
$ sudo locale-gen es_ES.UTF-8
```

una vez generado se puede utilizar en PHP

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_AR.UTF-8");
echo "es_AR: ".strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y").PHP_EOL;
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES.UTF-8","es_ES","esp");
echo "es_ES: ".strftime("%A %d de %B del %Y").PHP_EOL;

setlocale(LC_ALL,"fr_FR.UTF-8");
echo "fr_FR: ".strftime("%A %d %B %Y").PHP_EOL;

setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.UTF-8");
echo "en_US: ".strftime("%A %d %B %Y").PHP_EOL;
```

resultado:

```
$ ./testLocale.php
es_AR: lunes 23 de abril del 2018
es_ES: lunes 23 de abril del 2018
fr_FR: lundi 23 avril 2018
en_US: Monday 23 April 2018
```