# Días en Español con php

Tags: php, html, php7, function

!! necesito imprimir los días de la semana en español, pero los imprime en ingles. como lo cambio ?

```
$starDate = new DateTime('2018-06-01');
    $endDate = new DateTime('2018-06-30');
    while( $starDate <= $endDate){
         if($starDate->format('l')== 'Saturday' || $starDate->format('l')== 'Sunday'){
                        echo $starDate->format('d-m-y (l)')."<br/>";
         }
         $starDate->modify("+1 days");

    }
```

Comment: [Aquí tienes una respuesta, basada en una clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967), que trata de resolver el problema de una forma más global.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar un array asociativo asi:

```
$dias = array("Saturday" => "Sabado", "Sunday" => "Domingo");

$starDate = new DateTime('2018-06-01');
$endDate = new DateTime('2018-06-30');
while( $starDate <= $endDate){
     if($starDate->format('l')== 'Saturday' || $starDate->format('l')== 'Sunday'){
                    echo $starDate->format('d-m-y')
                        . ' (' . $dias[$starDate->format('l')] . " )<br/>";
     }
     $starDate->modify("+1 days");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

También podrías usar el [formato w](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) para obtener una representación numérica del día de la semana, 0 (para domingo) hasta 6 (para sábado) y usar un array para obtener los días en español. Por ejemplo:

```
$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
$starDate = new DateTime('2018-06-01');
    $endDate = new DateTime('2018-06-30');
    while( $starDate <= $endDate){

                        echo $starDate->format('d-m-y')."(".$dias[$starDate->format('w')].")<br/>";

         $starDate->modify("+1 days");

    }
```

Salida:

```
01-06-18(Viernes)
02-06-18(Sábado)
03-06-18(Domingo)
04-06-18(Lunes)
05-06-18(Martes)
06-06-18(Miercoles)
07-06-18(Jueves)
08-06-18(Viernes)
.
.
.
```