# ¿Cómo cambiar el formato de la fecha recibida en PHP?

Tags: php

Desde una consulta yo recibo la fecha de la siguiente manera:

```
2018-07-06 22:24:44
```

Por medio de:

```
<h4>'.$fecha.'</h4>
```

Como puedo cambiar ese formato, sin tener que modificar la base de datos, como puedo convertir esa fecha a este formato:

```
Julio 06,2018
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo mejor es trabajar con las funciones que ya tiene PHP

Eje:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES@euro","es_ES","esp");
$d = "2018-07-06";
$fecha = strftime("%d de %B de %Y", strtotime($date_post));
echo $fecha;
```

La salida de la fecha: `06 de julio de 2018`

También puedes jugar un poco con el código

Eje:

```
function obtenerFechaEnLetra($fecha){
    $dia= conocerDiaSemanaFecha($fecha);
    $num = date("j", strtotime($fecha));
    $anno = date("Y", strtotime($fecha));
    $mes = array('enero', 'febrero', 'marzo', 'abril', 'mayo', 'junio', 'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre', 'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre');
    $mes = $mes[(date('m', strtotime($fecha))*1)-1];
    return $dia.', '.$num.' de '.$mes.' del '.$anno;
}

function conocerDiaSemanaFecha($fecha) {
    $dias = array('Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado');
    $dia = $dias[date('w', strtotime($fecha))];
    return $dia;
}
```

La salida de la fecha: `Viernes, 6 de julio del 2018`

> En la documentación oficial de PHP, puedes encontrar las siguientes referencias.

- [Formatos de fecha](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.date.php)
- [Funciones strftime](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strftime.php)
- [Dar formato de fecha local](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Comment: Excelente amigo, con los ejemplos que me has dado puedo ir manipulando a mi gusto.

Answer (score 3):

prueba con el siguiente codigo, que debes asignar como quieres la fecha con `m-d-Y` que solo cambia el formato.

```
$fecha = "2018-07-07";
$fechaNueva = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($fecha));
```

otras formas de lograrlo

```
$fecha = "2018-07-07";
echo $fecha->format('d-m-Y');
```

Edicion 1:

```
$fecha = "2018-07-07"; //fecha de prueba
$mes = date("m",strtotime($fecha));  //obtenemos el mes en numero

 $monthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, 10)); //lo convertimos en cadena
 $year=date("y",strtotime($fecha));//obtenemos el año
 $dia=date("d",strtotime($fecha));// obtenemos el dia
 echo $monthName.' '.$dia.','.$year; // lo juntamos con el formato se quiere
```

El resultado es `July 07,18`, el nuevo problema es el idioma

Comment: amigo y no se puede obtener este formato con letras del mes así: **Julio 06,2018** el código que me has dado solo muestra la fecha así: 07-06-2018

Comment: @Eduardo edite mi respuesta con el formato que necesitas

Comment: Los nombres de los meses y los días vienen en inglés. Si los quieres en castellano, tendrás que implementar tu propia clase. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967), le pasas la fecha y tiene métodos para devolverte los días/meses en castellano.

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que IniDesing.com ya respondio adecuadamente, solucionando el problema del idioma

Comment: Cuando escribí mi comentario, la respuesta de @IniDesing no existía aún. Y en todo caso, siempre es bueno tener varias alternativas y elegir la mejor.

Comment: @A.Cedano revise la respuesta tuya y esta muy completa.

Comment: @x-rw Gracias :) +1 agradezco el tiempo dado.

Comment: pero ahi te limitas a una fecha especifica , no lo crees

Answer (score 3):

[Documentacion sobre Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Puedes implementar la función Date de PHP de esta manera:

Este es el código:

```
<?php //php 7.0.8

$today = date("F j, Y"); // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
echo $today;
?>
```

y te muestra algo así:

> July 7, 2018

Comment: @Eduardo si mi respuesta te ayudo a tu problema la puedes marcar como correcta, yo me base con la pregunta y como lo necesitabas.

Comment: el idioma el el problema de tu respuesta

Comment: @Simon Gracias :) +1 agradezco el tiempo dado.

Comment: @Eduardo okay si gustas una mejor y claro codigo o otras opciones mira aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25718115/trying-to-display-a-date-in-spanish (esta en ingles)

Comment: @Simon los [Stack Snippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet) son para código ejecutable en navegador únicamente :)

Comment: ok gracias por tu comentario

Answer (score 3):

Te recomiendo usar una librería muy buena para parsear tus fechas con PHP y fácilmente podrías usarlo con composer.

Para instalar esta librería con composer:

```
$ composer require fightbulc/moment
```

Fácil de parsear tus fechas con algunas cuantas lineas de código:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Se establece el lenguaje
\Moment\Moment::setLocale('es_ES');

$m = new \Moment\Moment('2018-07-06 22:24:44'); // Se agrega la fecha
echo $m->format('F j, Y'); // Imprime: julio 6, 2018
```

De esta y muchas otras formar podrías cambiar el formato de tus fechas.

Repositorio en Github: https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php

Comment: no es necesario usar ninguna libreria php puro lo puede hacer facilmente como en los ejemplos de arriba

Comment: Es una opción valida que se puede tomar en cuenta, ya que se estaría reutilizando código con esto nos ahorraríamos tiempo y solo nos tomaría algunas cuantas lineas de código. Aparte una librería nos puede dar muchas mas opciones pre fabricadas por otros desarrolladores para nuestra disposición.