# Separar fecha formato date(Y-m-d)

Tags: html

hola tengo este formato fecha date("Y-m-d") quiero separarlos por partes e imprimir solo mi mes de esa fecha .¿Como lo separo?

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$fecha=date("Y-m-d ");
```

Comment: Asi?: `$mes = date("m");`

Comment: lo hice asi pero me pone el mes actual y yo quiero el mes de la fecha que me imprime desde la base de datos

Comment: $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$fecha=date("Y-m-d ");
$partes = explode('-', $fecha);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]}";
          <td><?php echo $partes[1];?> pero solo me imprime el mes actual noviembre y yo quiero que imprima los meses de las demas fechas

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaría que trabajes usando Programación Orientada a Objetos, usando la clase `DateTime`.

Si en `$fecha` recibes una fecha así por ejemplo: `2018-11-15`:

```
$objFecha = new DateTime($fecha, new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));
$mes= $objFecha->format('m');

echo $mes;
```

La salida ahí sería `11`.

---

#### EDICIÓN

@Esther
La solución [que comentas aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/214114/separar-fecha-formato-datey-m-d#comment399022_214125) se puede mejorar. No hay necesidad de *marear* tanto los datos, haciendo `explode` con ellos.

```
$mostrarso=mysql_query($so); 
while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){ 
    $fecha_mes=$i[1]; 
    $partes = explode('-', $fecha_mes); 
    $_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]}"; 
    <td><?php echo $partes[1];?> </td>
}
```

Si aprendes a trabajar con objetos te vas a ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza y muchas líneas de código. Por ejemplo:

```
while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){ 
    $fecha=new DateTime($i[1]); 
    <td><?php echo $fecha->format('m');?> </td>
}
```

Y, si quieres mostrar el nombre del mes en castellano, puedes usar [esta clase utilitaria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967), pues con PHP per se, no es posible hacerlo  (si no te interesa toda la clase, adaptas la función de conversión de mes y nada más o traes el array de meses que usa la clase y conviertes *in situ*):

```
/*
   *Dado que sería una clase propia debes incluirla
   *aquí suponemos que la clase está en un archivo llamado fecha_es.php
   *en el directorio classes
*/
include('classes/fecha_es.php');
while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){ 
    $fecha=new FechaEs($i[1]); 
    <td><?php echo $fecha->getMMMM();?> </td>
}
```

Comment: como dije para mostrar el mes actual si sale pero yo quiero que salga el mes de cada fecha que esta en mi base de datos campo fecha con formato(Y--m-d)

Comment: @Esther si son muchos datos considera traerlos formateados directamente usando por ejemplo `SELECT MONTH(fecha) mes FROM ...` si sólo necesitas el mes. Si necesitas la fecha completa entonces puedes pasar cada fecha a una función de PHP para que te la formatee.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es obtener el mes, de un campo tipo: `Y-m-d` que provenga de tu base de datos te propongo el siguiente escenario

```
$fecha = "2018-11-25";

echo date('m', strtotime($fecha));
```

Donde `$fecha` simula ser un valor de tipo `DATE` que proviene de mi base de datos; posterior con la función `date()` de php paso como primer parámetro el valor que deseo obtener entre comillas, en este caso es el mes, posterior uso la función `strtotime()` a la cual le paso el nombre de la variable que contiene la fecha que deseo manipular

Cabe aclarar que:

1. Si uso `M` mayúscula obtengo el nombre del mes
2. Si uso `m` minpuscula obtengo el número del mes

La función `strtotime()` sirve y cito según php.net

(PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)

> strtotime — Convierte una descripción de fecha/hora textual en Inglés
>   a una fecha Unix

Enlace ala documentación oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php

Entonces si son varios datos puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT column1, column2, etc MONTH(columnaFecha) AS Mes FROM tu tabla;
```

Usas la función `MONTH()` a la cual por dentro de los parentesis le pasas el nombre de la columna que tiene la fecha; de ese modo llegan formateados directo de la DB

[Aqui tienes la referencia de dicha función en mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

Comment: pero no solo es para una sola fecha es para varias fechas distintas

Comment: te actualicé la respuesta @Esther

Comment: amigos ya lo encontre era de esta manera                 

             $mostrarso=mysql_query($so);
      while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){
            $fecha_mes=$i[1];
$partes = explode('-', $fecha_mes);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]}";

            <td><?php echo $partes[1];?>
    </td>

Comment: pero ahora quiero que me muestre el nombre del mes en vez del numero,como lo hago?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto

```
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
    $month = date("m");
    $year = date("y");
```

Para lo que lo vayas a ocupar, solamente, lo concatenas con `.`

Intenta esto...

```
 $fecha = $_POST['fecha']; 
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
     $fecha=date("Y-m-d "); 
     $month = date("m");
         $year = date("y");
         $day = date("d");

    $partes = explode('-', $month); 
    $_fecha = "$year.$month.$day";
    <td><?php echo $month;?> </td>
```

Comment: $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$fecha=date("Y-m-d ");
$partes = explode('-', $fecha);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]}";

en mi caso tengo esto pero mandarlo imprimir hago esto    <td><?php echo $partes[1];?>
    </td>