# php formato date

Tags: html

hola tengo duda como puedo pasar el mes de numero a nombre anteriormente tenia mi fecha en date(Y-m-d) queria imprimir el mes y puede dividirlo en partes con esto

```html
$mostrarso=mysql_query($so);
      while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){
            $fecha_mes=$i[1];
$partes = explode('-', $fecha_mes);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]} ";
```

lo imprimo de esta manera

```html
<td><?php echo   $partes[1]  ;?></td>
```

ahora quiero que ese valor del mes en vez de numero que sea el nombre del mes como Enero,febrero etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes convertir tu $fecha_mes a fecha con la función strtotime y después solo obtener el mes con la función date

ejemplo:

```
$nombremes=date("F",strtotime($fecha_mes));
```

puedes agregar setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES', 'esp_esp');
para que te lo cambie a español

otra opción seria con la función strftime con formato en español

```
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
   setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
   setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');

   $mostrarso=mysql_query($so);
   while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){
      $fecha_mes=$i[1];
      $nombre_mes=strftime("%B", strtotime($fecha_mes));
      $day=date("d",strtotime($fecha_mes));
      $year=date("Y",strtotime($fecha_mes));
      $_fecha = "{$day}-{$nombre_mes}-{$year} ";
      echo $nombre_mes;
   }
```

Comment: poniendo esa funcion me arroja el mes de diciembre

Comment: tenia un detalle deje $fecha_mes entre comillas,y debe ser sin comillas

Comment: $fecha_mes=$i[1];
$partes = explode('-', $fecha_mes);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]} "

                ?>                               <td><?php echo $partes[1];?></td> si tengo esto y lo imprime como numero del mes ahora lo que quiero es que imprima en vez de numero sea letra

Comment: prueba con la segunda opción

Comment: lo probe en algunas si me da el mes bien pero en otras me pone enero siendo que es octubre.¡como lo corrigo?

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
$nombremes=strftime("%B", strtotime($fecha_mes));
 
$fecha_mes=$i[1];
$partes = explode('-', $fecha_mes);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]} "

                ?>   asi quedo

Comment: date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES.UTF-8');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
$nombremes=strftime("%B", strtotime($fecha_mes=$i[1]));
$fecha_mes=$i[1];
$partes = explode('-', $fecha_mes);
$_fecha = "{$partes[2]}-{$partes[1]}-{$partes[0]} "
 listo ya me quedo muchisimas gracias @Juan Carlos

Answer (score 0):

Para mi nunca ha sido posible mostrar el nombre del mes en castellano usando `setlocale`. En mi caso hablo de una página web alojada en un servidor en inglés.

Como alternativa puedes hacer algo así:

```
/*Un array con los nombres de los meses*/
$esMeses = array("Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre");

/*
   *Vamos a crear a partir de tu fecha un verdadero objeto DateTime
   *y a sacar partida de él, obteniendo la representación numérica del mes
   *usando ->format('m')
   *luego buscaremos el valor de ese índice en $esMeses
   *Aquí [$numMes-1] restamos uno para aprovechar los índices naturales
   *del array: Enero sería 0, Febrero 1, etc, por eso restamos 1.
 */
while($i=mysql_fetch_array($mostrarso)){
    $fecha=new DateTime($i[1]);
    $numMes=$fecha->format('m');
    $nombreMes=$esMeses[$numMes-1];
    echo "<td>$nombreMes</td>";
}
```

Si piensas usar mucho esto o hacer otro tipo de *traducciones*, por ejemplo del día, etc, [considera usar una clase utilitaria parecida a esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967).