# Obtener los minutos en dos digitos en PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Hola es que estoy obteniendo los minutos de la base de datos, y me los muestra bien solo cuando es en dos digitos es decir de 10 hasta 59 pero de 0 a 9 me los muestra de un solo digito y a la hora de mostrarlos eso no se ve bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el de hora tengo este :

```
$col_hour = strftime("%I", DateTime::createFromFormat('H', $fila->hour)->getTimestamp());
```

Con el del meridiano este:

```
$col_format = DateTime::createFromFormat("H", $fila->hour);
$col_format = $col_format->format("a");
```

Con el mes este:

```
$col_month = strftime("%B", DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila->month)->getTimestamp()); 
$col_month = ucwords(strtolower($col_month));
```

Con el dia intente este:

```
$col_minute = strftime("%M", DateTime::createFromFormat('i', $fila->minute)->getTimestamp());
```

Pero no funciona, si alguno sabe cuál se usa para que me muestre `00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09.`

Igual podría agregarle un `0` cuando el length sea `1` pero prefiero agotar este recurso primero así que de ante mano gracias o los que me ayuden.

Comment: Estás haciendo un proceso totalmente inverso que *marea* los datos. O sea, al parecer ya tienes un objeto `DateTime` en `$fila`, por tanto, puedes mostrar partes de él haciendo esto por ejemplo:  `$col_minute->$fila->format('i');` la `i` es el parámetro para obtener los minutos con dos dígitos. Si quieres el mes con dos dígitos: `$col_mont=$fila->format('m');` Si `$fila` no fuera un objeto `DateTime`, puedes construir uno con los datos de la fecha/hora y luego aplicarle `format` como se ha indicado. [Aquí están todos los posibles formatos](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Answer (score 3):

Por las llamadas como `$fila->hour, $fila->month, $fila->minute` que se aprecian en tu código, parece que !`$fila` es ya un objeto `DateTime`!.

Si fuera así, no tienes que recurrir a algo como esto para representar el día, ni a ninguno de los procesos parecidos para las otras partes de tu objeto:

```
$col_minute = strftime("%M", DateTime::createFromFormat('i', $fila->minute)->getTimestamp());
```

Haciendo estás desperdiciando recursos y creando otro objeto `DateTime::createFromFormat('i', $fila->minute)->getTimestamp()` para sacar una información que ya tienes en el mismo objeto `$fila`.

Por ejemplo, si quieres el minuto de dos dígitos, basta con esto:

```
$col_minute->$fila->format('i');
```

Y así, cualquier parte de `$fila` la puedes obtener con `format`.

```
#Hora
$col_hour = $fila->format('H');

#Hora  AM PM
$col_meridiano = $fila->format("a"); 

#Mes   
$col_month = $fila->format('m');
```

Si por casualidad `$fila` no fuese un objeto `DateTime`, puedes crear uno a partir del dato inicial y luego sacar representaciones del mismo como necesites, sin tener que crear nuevos objetos para eso como haces hasta ahora.

En cuanto al mes, si quieres los nombres en castellano, puedes manejar un array con los nombres en castellano, obtener el número del mes siempre del mismo objeto, y buscarlo en el array restando `1`, puesto que los índices comienzan por `0` en los arrays de PHP.

Algo así:

```
 $esMeses = array(
                     "Enero", 
                     "Febrero", 
                     "Marzo", 
                     "Abril", 
                     "Mayo", 
                     "Junio", 
                     "Julio", 
                     "Agosto", 
                     "Septiembre", 
                     "Octubre", 
                     "Noviembre", 
                     "Diciembre"
                 );

$numMes=$fila->format('n');
echo $esMeses[$numMes-1];
```

Si observas bien, aquí hemos trabajado siempre sobre el mismo objeto que es `$fila`.

- [En esta página del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date.php) puedes ver todas las representaciones que puedes extraer de un mismo objeto `DateTime`.
- Si te interesa algo más avanzado, con respecto a la conversión de meses y días en castellano, [aquí puedes encontrar una aproximación interesante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967).

Answer (score 1):

Bueno algo simple sería validar el dígito en el mismo lugar donde lo muestra,, algo así:

```
<?php echo ($col_minute < 10) ? '0'.$col_minute : $col_minute; ?>
```

ya con eso para los minutos u horas que sean menores a 10, este le colocará el cero adicional al inicio.

Comment: A si lo que dije eso se puede agregar facil mira así lo tengo por ahora `$col_minute = strlen($fila->minute)==1 ? "0".$fila->minute : $fila->minute;`