# Obtener día de la semana en PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

Quiero mostrar lo siguiente a partir de una fecha es decir quiero que me diga

> lunes 2, martes 31,

y así por el estilo, pero no sé como, el lenguaje es PHP en este momento tengo esto

```
ucfirst(strtolower(strftime("%B", 
       DateTime::createFromFormat('m', $fila['month'])->getTimestamp())))
```

Y eso me convierte el mes a nombre del mes, pero no se como hacerlo con el día de la semana,

Tengo estos datos

```
$fila['month']
$fila['year']
$fila['day']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```
$date='2019-02-15';
echo date('l-d', strtotime($date));
//output:
Friday-15
```

Para mayor detalle te sugiero revisar la documentación:
[StrToTime PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Esta me funciono perfecto :  `date('l d', strtotime( date("Y")."-".$fila['month']."-".$fila['day']))` solo tengo una pregunta, como lo pongo en Español?

Al incio del codigo tengo esto :  `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');`

Comment: @AndrésVélez, mi experiencia es que `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');` no funciona siempre. En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967) he puesto un ejemplo de una clase utilitaria que se puede incorporar a tu programa para obtener días o meses en castellano a partir de una fecha. También te recomiendo que acostumbres a trabajar siempre con objetos `DateTime` en vez de cadena. El objeto representa un objeto sobre el cual puedes hacer cálculos con facilidad o puedes usar el mismo objeto para imprimir partes de él, la cadena sólo te sirve para hacer un `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

podrías utilizar dos array's uno para días y otro para meses.

```
<?php
$dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
$meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
echo $dias[date('w')]." ".date('d')." de ".$meses[date('n')-1]. " del ".date('Y') ;
//Salida: Viernes 24 de Febrero del 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP tiene varias clases para trabajar con fechas que nos facilitan mucho las cosas, para recorrer un periodo de fechas y motrarlas te puede apoyar en [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) y sus métodos [`DateTime::modify`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.modify.php) y [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php), así como en las clases [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateperiod.php) y [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.dateinterval.php)

Ejemplo explicado

```
<?php
// definimos 2 array uno para los nombre de los dias y otro para los nombres de los meses
$nombresDias = array("Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miercoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado" );
$nombresMeses = array(1=>"Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");

// establecemos la fecha de inicio
$inicio =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-02-15', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
// establecemos la fecha final (fecha de inicio + dias que queramos)
$fin =  DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2019-02-15', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Madrid'));
$fin->modify( '+10 day' );

// creamos el periodo de fechas
$periodo = new DatePeriod($inicio, new DateInterval('P1D') ,$fin);

// recorremos las dechas del periodo
foreach($periodo as $date){
    // definimos la variables para verlo mejor
    $nombreDia = $nombresDias[$date->format("w")];
    $nombreMes = $nombresMeses[$date->format("n")];
    $numeroDia = $date->format("j");
    $anyo = $date->format("Y");
    // mostramos los datos
    echo $nombreDia.' '.$numeroDia.' de '.$nombreMes.' de '.$anyo.'<br>';
}

?>
```

Resultado:

```
Viernes 15 de Febrero de 2019
Sábado 16 de Febrero de 2019
Domingo 17 de Febrero de 2019
Lunes 18 de Febrero de 2019
Martes 19 de Febrero de 2019
Miercoles 20 de Febrero de 2019
Jueves 21 de Febrero de 2019
Viernes 22 de Febrero de 2019
Sábado 23 de Febrero de 2019
Domingo 24 de Febrero de 2019
```