# No mostrar año de startDate si es igual a endDate

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, date

En una tabla con fechas start_date y end_date no mostrar el año de start_date si es igual al de end_date

Ej:

Tengo una tabla que muestra

11 septiembre 2019 hasta 30 septiembre 2019

10 Diciembre 2019 hasta 30 Enero 2020

Lo que se pretende es mostrar

**11 septiembre** al 30 septiembre 2019

10 Diciembre 2019 hasta 30 Enero 2020

Las fechas son extraídas mediante consulta con valor date, no son siempre las mismas fechas pueden variar por lo tanto debe ser automático.

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
$result;
$conn = dbConnect();
$sql = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%e %M %Y") start_date, 
DATE_FORMAT(end_date, "%e %M %Y") end_date FROM dates_control';
$result = $conn->query($sql);       
$rows = $result->fetchall();
?>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Fechas</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($rows as $row) {   
    ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <?php echo $row ['start_date'];?> al <?php echo $row['end_date']; ?>
                            </td>


    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Diría que aquí lo de menos es el locale. Realmente es una cuestión banal mostrar las fechas en inglés o en español u otro idioma.

El requerimiento es más serio: **implementar un lógica robusta** que cubra los diferentes casos de una forma adecuada. Cuando eso está hecho, todo lo demás viene por añadidura.

En tu caso, lo más simple sería:

1. Evitar obtener los datos formateados de la base de datos. Eso va a dificultar las comparaciones posteriores que hay que hacer.
2. Establecer los posibles casos y manejarlos (este es el núcleo de la lógica que hay que implementar). Los casos posibles son:

   a. Mismo año, mismo mes

   b. Mismo año, distinto mes

   c. Distinto año, mismo mes

   d. Distinto año, distinto mes

   Una **lógica robusta** significa que el código debe ser capaz de determinar esas cuatro posibilidades y mostrar una cadena adecuada en consecuencia.

Veamos un ejemplo donde se resuelve el problema, poniendo en práctica lo que he mencionado antes. Aquí, dado que no estoy consultado a la base de datos, he puesto en `$rows` unos datos ficticios, y la fecha se obtiene en formato `yyyymmdd`, se crean objeto `DateTime` con los datos y se sacan los elementos que hay que comparar aparte, en variables, las cuales servirán también para construir la cadena definitiva.

Para hacer las 4 evaluaciones del núcleo lógico se usan *operadores ternarios*  concatenados, que nos evitarían demasiados `if`.

El código sería este:

<kbd>[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/JBHOPN7759)</kbd>

```
$rows=array (
                array ('start_date'=>20190911,'end_date'=>20190930),
                array ('start_date'=>20191002,'end_date'=>20191101),
                array ('start_date'=>20200204,'end_date'=>20210227),
                array ('start_date'=>20200301,'end_date'=>20210430),
            );

foreach ($rows as $row){
    $start=new DateTime($row['start_date']);
    $startDay=$start->format('d');
    $startMonth=$start->format('F');
    $startYear=$start->format('Y');
    $end=new DateTime($row['end_date']);
    $endDay=$end->format('d');
    $endMonth=$end->format('F');
    $endYear=$end->format('Y');

/*
    *a. Mismo año, mismo mes
    *b. Mismo año, distinto mes
    *c. Distinto año, mismo mes
    *d. Distinto año, distinto mes
    */
    $s=(
        ($startMonth == $endMonth && $startYear==$endYear) ? "De $startDay a $endDay $startMonth $startYear" : 
            ( ($startMonth!==$endMonth && $startYear==$endYear) ? "De $startDay $startMonth a $endDay $endMonth $startYear" : 
                ( ($startMonth==$endMonth && $startYear!==$endYear) ? "De $startDay $startMonth $startYear a $endDay $endMonth $endYear" : 
                                                                     "De $startDay $startMonth $startYear a $endDay $endMonth $endYear"
                )
             )
        );
    echo $s.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Con los datos manejados (uno por cada posibilidad), tendríamos esta salida:

```
De 11 a 30 September 2019
De 02 October a 01 November 2019
De 04 February 2020 a 27 February 2021
De 01 March 2020 a 30 April 2021
```

Como ya dije, poner el nombre en español u otro idioma es lo de menos. Te puedes valer de una clase utilitaria, o tratar de cambiar el formato local (en mi caso preferiría la clase utilitaria, ver por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967)).

Comment: muchas gracias! Funciona perfecto, pero setlocale no funciona, y la clase utilitaria no puedo hacerla funcionar

Comment: @PacúWeb yo prefiero para estos casos una clase utilitaria precisamente porque `setlocale` no funciona igual en todos los entornos, depende del servidor, del lugar donde esté ubicado, etc. Cuando hablo de clase utilitaria me refiero a una clase que tú mismo creas y la usas para esos fines. En este caso, la clase utilitaria te serviría para mostrar objetos fecha en español en cualquier parte de tu programa o en cualquier aplicación. La única desventaja es que la clase no existe en sí, debes crearla tú. Eso te abre una perspectiva nueva e interesante: crear tu propia biblioteca de código :)