# Fecha en español

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente problemática con la fechas. Cuando guardamos una fecha en un base de datos se guarda `yyyy-mm-dd` (1979-03-31).

Tengo unas fechas guardadas en mi base de datos, pero al mostrarla con `echo` quisiera que se mostrara la fecha en el formato que por lo general usamos, que es 31-03-1979:

```
BD:
Nacimiento 
1979-03-31

PHP:
date_default_timezone_set("America/Caracas");
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_VE.UTF-8','esp');

Fecha de Nacimiento: <?php echo $data['Nacimiento'];?>
```

Se muestra `1979-03-31`, pero quiero que muestre `31-03-1979`. Ya he probado con varias funciones de `date` pero sin obtener ningún buen resultado.

Comment: Por favor añade el código con las funciones de date que has probado. Y no, no es evidente que una fecha se guarde con el formato que indicas; depende del tipo de dato de la columna. Así pues, es importante que indiques en tu pregunta (editándola) de qué tipo de dato es la columna que guarda las fechas y cómo las recuperas desde PHP.

Comment: Los formatos de fecha se pueden modificar tanto al obtener los datos en mysql con date_format, como en php con date, por ejemplo. ¿Qué has intentado y dónde te falla?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para dar formato a una fecha puedes hacer uso de multitud de funciones en PHP:

- [`date()`](https://php.net/es/date): da formato personalizado a una marca de tiempo.
- [`strftime()`](https://php.net/es/strftime): da formato a una marca de tiempo, de manera similar a `date()`, pero soporta localización de formatos y textos (días de la semana y mes).
- [`DateTime::format()`](https://php.net/es/datetime.format): da formato personalizado a un objeto `DateTime`.

## Ejemplo con `date()`

```
<?php
$data['Nacimiento'] = '1979-03-31';
/* Convertimos la fecha a marca de tiempo */
$marca = strtotime($data['Nacimiento']);
?>
...
Fecha en base de datos: <?= $data['Nacimiento'] ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 1: <?= date('r', $marca) ?><br/
Fecha de Nacimiento 2: <?= date('l j \d\e F \d\e Y', $marca) ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 3: <?= date('d-m-Y', $marca) ?><br/>
```

Resultado:

```
Fecha en base de datos: 1979-03-31
Fecha de Nacimiento 1: Sat, 31 Mar 1979 00:00:00 -0400
Fecha de Nacimiento 2: Saturday 31 de March de 1979
Fecha de Nacimiento 3: 31-03-1979
```

La función `date()` no soporta localización, por lo que las cadenas de texto de días de la semana y meses siempre saldrán en inglés.

## Ejemplo con `strftime()`

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Caracas");
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_VE.UTF-8','esp');
$data['Nacimiento'] = '1979-03-31';
/* Convertimos la fecha a marca de tiempo */
$marca = strtotime($data['Nacimiento']);
?>
...
Fecha en base de datos: <?= $data['Nacimiento'] ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 1: <?= strftime('%c', $marca) ?><br/
Fecha de Nacimiento 2: <?= strftime('%A %e de %B de %Y', $marca) ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 3: <?= strftime('%x', $marca) ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 4: <?= strftime('%d-%m-%Y', $marca) ?><br/>
```

Resultado:

```
Fecha en base de datos: 1979-03-31
Fecha de Nacimiento 1: sáb 31 mar 1979 00:00:00 -04
Fecha de Nacimiento 2: sábado 31 de marzo de 1979
Fecha de Nacimiento 3: 31/03/79
Fecha de Nacimiento 4: 31-03-1979
```

Esta función puede alterar su comportamiento según la configuración local que has configurado con [`setlocale()`](https://php.net/es/setlocale).

Ejemplos de [parámetros de formato](https://php.net/es/strftime#refsect1-function.strftime-parameters):

> **%c**: Marca preferida de la fecha y hora basadas en el localismo. Ejemplo: Tue Feb 5 00:45:10 2009 para el 5 de febrero de 2009 a las 12:45:10 AM

> **%x**: Representación preferida de la fecha basada en la configuración local, sin la hora. Ejemplo: 02/05/09 para el 5 de febrero de 2009

## Ejemplo con `DateTime::format()`

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Caracas");
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_VE.UTF-8','esp');
$data['Nacimiento'] = '1979-03-31';
/* Convertimos la fecha a un objeto DateTime */
$fecha = new DateTime($data['Nacimiento']);
/* El formato que deseas */
$formato1 = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'es-ES',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Caracas',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    'dd-MM-yyyy'
);
/* Un ejemplo de formato con cadenas de texto */
$formato2 = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'es-ES',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'America/Caracas',
    IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN,
    "eeee d 'de' LLLL 'de' yyyy"
);
?>
...
Fecha en base de datos: <?= $data['Nacimiento'] ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 1: <?= strftime(
    '%A %e de %B de %Y', $fecha->getTimestamp()
) ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 2: <?= $fecha->format('d-m-Y') ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 3: <?= $formato1->format($fecha) ?><br/>
Fecha de Nacimiento 4: <?= $formato2->format($fecha) ?><br/>
```

Resultado:

```
Fecha en base de datos: 1979-03-31
Fecha de Nacimiento 1: sábado 31 de marzo de 1979
Fecha de Nacimiento 2: 31-03-1979
Fecha de Nacimiento 3: 31-03-1979
Fecha de Nacimiento 4: sábado 31 de marzo de 1979
```

En este ejemplo he hecho uso de `$fecha->format('d-m-Y')` para dar salida al formato deseado `dd-mm-aaaa` y, además, he hecho uso de textos localizados haciendo uso de `strftime()` convirtiendo `$fecha` en marca de tiempo con `$fecha->getTimestamp()`.

También he agregado, a sugerencia de [A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) (gracias), un par de ejemplos de cómo usar la clase para el formato internacional de fechas [`IntlDateFormatter`](https://php.net/es/class.intldateformatter) de la [extensión internacional (intl)](https://www.php.net/intl) de PHP.

Comment: Yo crearía a partir de la fecha un objeto `DateTime`. La ventaja es que a partir de un mismo objeto puedes mostrar cualquier dato (por ejemplo en el caso de necesitar mostrar la fecha por un lado y la hora por otro), otra ventaja es poder hacer cálculos, establecer intervalos, períodos, etc. Por ejemplo, la API de SQL Server para PHP te da los campos de fecha directamente como objetos `DateTime`, no como una cadena, precisamente por la enorme ventaja de trabajar con un objeto más conforme al dato.

Comment: Me dejé llegar por el "fecha en español" y el `setlocale()` que usó. Por desgracia `DateTime` no soporta localizar textos, por lo que hay que tirar de `DateTime::getTimestamp()` y `strftime()` para obtener los textos en castellano. Aún así, debido a que lo que solicita son formatos numéricos de fecha, voy a editar mi respuesta con tu apunte.

Comment: Particularmente soy cada día más fan de los objetos, porque es relativamente fácil extenderlos, creando incluso tu propia biblioteca de código. En el caso de necesitar nombres de meses o días en castellano sería muy fácil crear tu propia clase utilitaria ([aquí un ejemplo simple](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967)). `DateTime` funciona también con la [extensión internacional](https://www.php.net/intl) de PHP, sólo que hay que asegurarse de que la misma esté instalada en el entorno donde correrá el código.

Comment: Gracias por este último apunte, suelo usar `DateTime` con frecuencia, pero desconocía la existencia de `IntlDateFormatter`. He agregado más ejemplos.