# Nombre del mes anterior php

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un consulta en php para saber el total de ventas del mes anterior, el cual ya tengo ese resultado.

Necesito llamar el mes anterior pero solo consigo que me muestre el mes actual para ello estoy ocupando el siguiente codigo.

```php
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
echo iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8',strftime("%B"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de dos formas:

### Con localidad

Si tienes la localidad en español disponible, puedes lograrlo pasando el formato relativo `last day of previous month` a `strtotime`:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
echo strftime("%B", strtotime("last day of previous month"));
```

Si no ves tu fecha en español, es porque no tienes la localidad disponible.

Ten en cuenta que aquí solamente tienes una cadena, no un objeto fecha.

### Si necesitas trabajar con objetos

Si necesitas ese dato para operaciones complejas, te aconsejo que crees un objeto fecha y que uses métodos adecuados para traducir las salidas.

Si te interesa permanecer en un contexto de objeto, tú puedes usar la clase [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) para crear un objeto pasándole en el constructor el [formato relativo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.relative.php#102947) `'last day of last month'`.

```
$last = new DateTime('last day of last month'); 
var_dump($last);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-12-31 21:26:25.214180"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

A partir de ahí, puedes usar el método [`format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php) de la misma clase para mostrar la fecha como necesites.

Por ejemplo:

```
echo $last->format('F').PHP_EOL;
echo $last->format('M').PHP_EOL;
```

**Salida:**

```
December
Dec
```

Con `format()` tienes que usar los parámetros según lo indicado [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php).

Conviene tener en cuenta que `$last` **es un objeto `DateTime`** y que por tanto puedes operar con él usando cualquiera de los métodos de que dispone esa clase, incluyendo sus clases relacionadas, para calcular períodos, intervalos, etc si fuera necesario.

Para traducir, puedes usar [la extensión internacional de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.intldateformatter.php), sólo que ésta debe estar instalada en tu entorno (no será complicado instalarla si no está).

O bien, puedes crear tu propia clase utilitaria de traducción el español, lo cual será sumamente sencillo, [ver por ejemplo esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967).

¿Y por qué tanto rollo? Pues porque no es lo mismo trabajar con una cadena simple, en contextos donde necesitas la fecha para operaciones complejas.

Comment: como puedo lograr que se muestre en español?

Answer (score 0):

Con base al código que ya utilizas, puedes incluir:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
echo iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'UTF-8',strftime("%B",mktime(0,0,0,date("m")-1,date("d"),date("Y"))));
```

Con la instrucción de mktime estas pasándole la instrucción de generar una fecha, el 4 parámetro es el mes, y le pones mes -1 para indicar el anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es, primero calcular la fecha de hace un mes y luego extraer el nombre del mes de dicha fecha:

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES");
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES", 'Spanish_Spain', 'Spanish');
  echo strftime("%B", strtotime(date("d-m-Y",strtotime(date("d-m-Y"). "- 1 month")));
```