# Resultado de datename en español SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, webservice, rest

Estoy creando un webservice rest con php en donde se obtiene el dia de la fecha de una base de datos sql server y retorna un json como este:

```
[{"DataInicio":"Friday, 5 de August del 2022"}]
```

La consulta sql está hecha de la siguiente manera

```
    SET LANGUAGE Spanish; 
SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(DW,CONVERT(datetime,[x].[Datainicio],101)), ', ', DATENAME(day,[x].[Datainicio]), ' de ', DATENAME(month,[x].[Datainicio]), ' del ' , DATENAME(year,[x].[Datainicio])) as DataInicio FROM [Agendamento] AS [x]
```

Utilizo SET LANGUAGE Spanish; para realizar la consulta y que me retorne los días y el mes en español, en el managment de SQL server me trae correctamente de la siguiente manera:

```
Domingo, 19 de Agosto del 2018
```

Pero en el webservice creado con PHP al utilizar SET LANGUAGE Spanish; no me trae ningún resultado.

Agrego mi código PHP

```
$query = "SET LANGUAGE Spanish; 
SELECT CONCAT(DATENAME(DW,CONVERT(datetime,[x].[Datainicio],101)), ', ', DATENAME(day,[x].[Datainicio]), ' de ', DATENAME(month,[x].[Datainicio]), ' del ' , DATENAME(year,[x].[Datainicio])) as DataInicio FROM [Agendamento] AS [x]";

$params = array();
$this->conn->prepare($query);
$response   = $result->execute($params);
```

Qué me faltaría agregar para que la fecha me traiga en español en mi webservice rest?

Comment: Si el código SQL funciona, lo que deberías mostrar en la pregunta es el código que no funciona, es decir, el código PHP con el que manejas la petición y que dices no trae ningún resultado. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: Lo que no me funciona es la consulta sql y es la que mostré más arriba, el codigo PHP funciona, lee bien por favor antes de comentar

Comment: Lee tú tu propia pregunta. Has afirmado que: *en el managment de SQL server me trae correctamente*, es decir, en el entorno SQL **funciona** y has escrito que: *Pero en el webservice creado con PHP al utilizar SET LANGUAGE Spanish; no me trae ningún resultado.* es decir, en el entorno PHP **no funciona**.

Comment: Y esa es mi consulta, porque en el managmente me funciona la consulta sql y retorna el resultado en español y en PHP no, me trae resultado en PHP solo si le remuevo SET LANGUAGE Spanish; pero ese resultado me retorna en inglés

Comment: Es necesario ver el código PHP que no funciona, puede que no muestre nada debido a algún error en ese código. Por ejemplo, muchos controladores no admiten más de una consulta desde PHP o tienen su propia función para multi query, y `SET LANGUAGE` es una consulta, mientras que el `SELECT` es otra. Sin ver el código PHP que usas para consultar poco podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Es más, yo no haría conversiones en la instrucción SQL, simplemente traería la fecha como tal, incluso como un objeto `DateTime` a PHP y haría la conversión a nivel de PHP.

Comment: Agregue mi código php, hice la migración desde un servidor windows en donde el mismo código funcionaba correctamente a un servidor ubuntu 18.04, la base de datos está instalado en el mismo servidor ubuntu

Comment: Es como te decía antes, `$query` es una consulta múltiple (hay dos instrucciones SQL), ¿qué controlador usas para conectarte a la base de datos en tu entorno PHP? Algunos controladores tienen funciones específicas para ejecutar múltiples consultas.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces como podria cambiar el idioma ya que no quiero crear un switch para traducir los dias y meses a español, el controlador que utilizo es DBLIB

Comment: No tienes que crear un switch, si necesitas fechas en español puedes crear una clase utilitaria para que te convierta los nombres de meses y días a español (esto será lo más ligero de todas las opciones) o trabajar con la configuración de PHP o con el módulo de internacionalización. Considera que de otro modo tu código es más costoso: una consulta adicional que afecta a la configuración de la BD o código que afecta la configuración del servidor.

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo básico de lo que sería una clase utilitaria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/158340/29967). Le pasarías el objeto `DateTime` que recibes en la consulta SQL y podrías formatear la fecha a español sin más historia. Así quitarías los `CONVERT` en tu instrucción SQL, obteniendo un objeto `DateTime` puro desde la base de datos, optimizando el código.

Comment: te recomendaria crear un procedimiento almacenado para consumir API asi te quitas la liada que te tas dando...

Answer (score 0):

Deberias implementar un procedimiento almacenado:

[Link Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-language-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetDateSpanish

BEGIN

    SET LANGUAGE Spanish
    SELECT
        CONCAT(
            DATENAME(
                DW,
                CONVERT(DATETIME,X.Datainicio, 101)
            ),
            ', ',
            DATENAME(DAY, X.Datainicio),
            ' de ',
            DATENAME(MONTH, X.Datainicio),
            ' del ',
            DATENAME(YEAR, X.Datainicio)
        ) AS DataInicio
    FROM
        Agendamento AS X

GO
```

como llamarias al procedimiento almacenado [Doc Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21466870/17161735):

```
<?php 

  $sth = $dbh->prepare("exec GetDateSpanish");
  $sth->execute();

  while($result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        var_dump($result);
  }
```